# State depends on another state , Android Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a composable which gets an integer which is a mutable state !

The *integer* is a timer value ! like 0 which increases on every second

What i must do inside the composable is convert to representable string like for 60 seconds I will display 1minute

so I do this

```
    val timeString = remember {
       mutableStateOf("00:00")
    }

    val durationString  = if(duration!=0) {
    var secondTime = ((duration / 1000) % 60).toString()
    var minuteTime = ((((duration / 1000) / 60) % 60)).toString()
    if (secondTime.length == 1) {
        secondTime = "0$secondTime"
    }
    if (minuteTime.length == 1) {
        minuteTime = "0$minuteTime"
    }
    "$minuteTime:$secondTime"
}else{
    "00:00"
}


timeString.value = durationString

         Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
            text = timeString.value,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4
        )
```

But the text does not update but since duration is a mutable state if I use it directly the text updates , so I tried LaunchedEffect but it did't work I would like to know what is the best way I can do this in compose !

Comment: I also tried to create anther text state which and used the launchedEffect to update the text state value but it does not update the Text

Comment: wrap your if with a ``remember(duration) { /* your if */}``
If you want to know about the why I suggest to read up on the remember documentation

Comment: Its not working

Comment: Can you please also provide the code of your state creation / passing

Comment: duration is a parameter which is a mutable state which changes and when set directly works !

Comment: You can do something different. Define a `ViewModel` with a `CountDownTimer? ` and in your Composable function use something like: `val secs = countTimeViewModel.seconds.observeAsState()`

Comment: text = "${recordingDurationState.value / 60}m ${recordingDurationState.value % 60}s"

This works but I would love to know the solution to the problem above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like mentioned in my comment you need to warp what should be recalculated each time inside a remember and pass the state as a key (needed so that compose knows that it has to update the String).

See example code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun outer() {
    val durationState = remember { mutableStateOf(600000) }
    LaunchedEffect(durationState) {
        // This not how you do a timer but close enough
        val step = 1000
        repeat(600000.div(step)) {
            durationState.value = durationState.value - step
            delay(step.toLong())
        }
    }
    questionComposable(durationState)
}

@Composable
fun questionComposable(durationState: MutableState<Int>) {
    val durationString = remember(durationState.value) {
        val duration = durationState.value
        if (duration != 0) {
            var secondTime = ((duration / 1000) % 60).toString()
            var minuteTime = ((((duration / 1000) / 60) % 60)).toString()
            if (secondTime.length == 1) {
                secondTime = "0$secondTime"
            }
            if (minuteTime.length == 1) {
                minuteTime = "0$minuteTime"
            }
            "$minuteTime:$secondTime"
        } else {
            "00:00"
        }

    }
    Text(
        text = durationString,
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4
    )
}
```

Comment: I am getting duration state as a parameter from parent composable

Comment: but its remembered , the only time it works is if I put it directly , also the value of the duration state is updated using a timerTask that updates the value every second

Comment: this code also works when you pass it like ``fun ex(durationState: MutableState<Int>)``

Comment: Make a gist or similar with the complete composable i guess the error is outside of the provided stuff.

Comment: the error isn't outside , if it would have been then the direct state would not work , 
When I set the state directly to composable it works  , 
text = "${durationState.value / 60}m ${durationState.value % 60}s"  -> THIS WORKSS!

Comment: No need to be annoyed, I can only guess what's on the outside, I updated the solution to resemble your example more closely. This code runs on Compose Desktop and Android

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231375/discussion-between-waqas-tahir-and-2jan222).